# How can i get discord.py to display name while logging every message to a file?

Tags: python

My Issue is, I cant get my bot to display the Member Author, Date and Message. Here is the error:

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

My Code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message, ctx):
        #await client.send_message(message.channel, discord.Message.author)
        messagestr = ""
        messagestr = ('{0.content}'.format(message))
        file_open()
        print(device_time()+" "+ctx.message.author+" "+"Message: "+messagestr)
        out1 = ""
        out1 = messagestr
        f1 = open('logs.txt','a')

        out1 = out1.replace('\n', '')
        out1 = (device_time()+" "+out1+'\r')
        f1.write(device_time()+" "+"Message: "+messagestr)
        f1.close()
        f1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` does not take `ctx` so remove that from the function and instead of `ctx.message.author` use `message.author`

Answer (score 0):

First of all [on_message discord.py event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) doesn't takes `ctx`, it only takes `message`, this is what directly causes the error.

Then you are using +'s python concatenation methods which is not bad but python's [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) are way better to format strings as f-strings directly convert the variable type to string (so no need to use str() function)

Also, think about using [PEP-8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which makes your codes looks nicer and more easy to read.
For example, you use `messagestr = ""`, for python's interpreter, this is ok and won't throw a error but for humans this is really ugly to use, in python you should use [snake_case](http://www.google.com/search?q=snake_case) so `messagestr` would become `message_str = None`

Here's what would i have done :

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        #await client.send_message(message.channel, str(message.author))
        message_str = message.content
        file_open()
        print(f'{device_time()} {message.author} Message: {messagestr}')
        out = message_str.replace('\n', '')
        file = open('logs.txt','a')

        out = f'{device_time()} {out} \r' #Note : message.created_at would be a useful function here to replace device_time()
        file.write(f'{device_time()} Message: {message_str}')
        file.close()
```